# add new object to firebase with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add new object to my database on firebase `

```
export class AppComponent {
  courses$: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  course$;ang
  author$

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.courses$ = db.list('/courses');
    this.course$ = db.object('/courses/1').valueChanges();
    this.author$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
  }

  add(course: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.courses$.push(course.value);
    course.value = '';
  }

}
```

but i found this error:

> [ts] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Comment: `db.list('/courses');` is returning string that's why you are getting this error

Comment: I edited it to: this.courses$ = db.list('/courses').valueChanges(); but not working

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
export class AppComponent {
  courses$: Observable<any[]>;
  course$;
  author$

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.courses$ = db.list('/courses').valueChanges();
    this.course$ = db.object('/courses/1').valueChanges();
    this.author$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
  }

  add(course: HTMLInputElement): void {
    this.db.list('/courses').push(course.value);
    course.value = '';
  }

}
```